# Pacman: How to choose default choice when it asks to replace a package?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pacman-package-manager

I'm working with docker and I try to make a Dockerfile including some pacman upgrade/installation. But at some point of the upgrading process, pacman asks if I want to replace some package with an other.
But in the case of a Dockerfile, an error occurs.

How could I avoid that? I have no idea. :S
I though there could have been an option, but in this case I didn't find which one.

Here is my (simple) Dockerfile :

```
# Test with Archlinux
FROM base/archlinux
MAINTAINER name firstname <name.firstname@example.com>
RUN pacman -Suy && pacman-db-upgrade && pacman -S python-pip
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can use option `--noconfirm` in pacman to bypass any confirmation message it asks. Because of official Arch image is not updated frequently the update process needs some steps that need confirmation. Try using this Dockerfile to avoid problems:

```
# Test with Archlinux
FROM base/archlinux
MAINTAINER name firstname <name.firstname@example.com>
RUN pacman -Sy --noconfirm &&\ 
    pacman -S pacman --noconfirm &&\
    pacman-db-upgrade &&\
    pacman -S --noconfirm python-pip
```